# Null pointer exception in TextView

Tags: android, roboguice

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView 
        android:id = "@+id/postQues"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Post A Question" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/postAnswer"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:text="Post Your Answer" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/submit"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:clickable="true"     
              android:text="Submit" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my activity:

```
package com.qstack.quizbox;

import roboguice.activity.RoboActivity;
import roboguice.inject.ContentView;
import roboguice.inject.InjectView;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.main.R;

@ContentView(R.layout.q_box)
public class QuizBox extends RoboActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.postQues) TextView postQues;
    @InjectView(R.id.postAnswer) EditText postAnswer;
    //@InjectView(R.id.submit) Button submitA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PostQuestion postQuestion = new PostQuestion();
        postQues.setText(postQuestion.postQuestion());

        submitA.setOnClickListener(submitAnswerListener);
    }

     private OnClickListener submitAnswerListener = new OnClickListener() {
         //onClick view
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String answer;
             answer = postA.getText().toString();

             CheckAnswer checkAnswer = new CheckAnswer();

             if (answer == checkAnswer.checkAnswer()) {
                 postA.setText("Correct");
             }
         }
     };
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception at line number 48, caused because postQues = null. When I remove postAnswer from the code, there is no null pointer exception. I've cleaned my project and all that. Any help

Comment: can you paste your roboactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourxml); // you have missed this.....
    PostQuestion postQuestion = new PostQuestion();
    postQues.setText(postQuestion.postQuestion());
    submitA.setOnClickListener(submitAnswerListener);
}
```

Comment: hello, I have the same problem here, BUT as Puck did I also add @ContentView(R.layout.mine) above the public class line. Why isn't works ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet on your answers, but people miss the point: he, like me, is using `RoboGuice` to inject views and stuff.

The sole purpouse of this framework is to avoid the boiler-plate part on `onCreate()` where you won't need to use `setContentView` and `findViewById()` anymore !

As to why he gets a `NullePointerException`, I don't know. I happen to have the same issue on one of my activies although it works just fine on all the other...

**[EDIT]**

I found the solution : I mixed up the type of two views.
If you put `setContentView()` where it is supposed to be, you will get the error.
The application wil say it cannot assign. Because the type doesn't match.
Therefore you get a nice

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

But if you use `RoboGuice` framework, you get such error (well in my case I did not). However, all you views will all be `null`.

Hope it will help someone someday.

Comment: Thanks, helped me to figure out the problem!

Comment: @McLovin you're welcome. `Rboguice` is quite handy but you have to be meticulous in order to avoid strange exceptions that would forward you to a wrong path with no solution since Roboguice changes the way views are instanciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and followed Mackovich's suggestions. He's right in pointing out that you don't need setContentView() with RoboGuice, as long as you annotate your activity with @ContentView.

In my case, the issue was caused by the fact that I had replaced an AutoCompleteTextView with an EditText, but forgot to make the same replacement in the activity with corresponding @InjectView. This was causing my NullPointerException.

Again, like Mackovich said, if I use setContentView() instead of @ContentView, the stacktrace gives me a more useful message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't assign class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText value android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText@426ce048 to class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView field usernameTextView
```

I guess that's an argument against using Roboguice's @ContentView, at least until a fix is made in order to show the correct stacktrace.

Comment: So how it answers the question?

Comment: It answers the question by pointing out that you should use setContentView() instead of @ContentView, in order to see a clearer exception message. Like I said, in my case the NPE was caused by the fact that I was trying to inject the wrong view type. But I only figured this out after I used setContentView().

Comment: Thanks, helped me to figure out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.the_xml)` first (right after `super.onCreate()`). Otherwise RoboGuice doesn't know what to inject into your variables!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the following line in your code,

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

which should be after this line of `onCreate()` method

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed that line

```
 setContentView(R.layout.xml_filename);
```